# GSON create one object from complex object

Tags: annotations, gson

Imagine that we have the following 2 classes:

```
public class Test {
    private String element1;
    private SubTest subTest;
}
public class SubTest {
    private String element2;
}
```

If I create json from `Test` class I will have next string:

```
{element1:null,subTest:{element2:null}}
```

But I need result json with this view:

```
{element1:null,subTest_element2:null}
```

I know that I can do this by creating an adapter where I can implement serialize method as I want, but I need something else, for example annotation, which I will put under `private SubTest subTest;`

Could someone help me with that?

Answer (score 2):

Gson 2.2's new [TypeAdapterFactory](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/TypeAdapterFactory.html) interface gives you the hooks to inspect the incoming type's annotations and to define a type adapter based on those annotations. Here's a full example that looks for a field annotated `JsonInlined`. If it is found, the type adapter will serialize the outer object as the inner object.

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@interface JsonInlined {}

static class InlinedFieldFactory implements TypeAdapterFactory {
  public <T> TypeAdapter<T> create(Gson gson, TypeToken<T> type) {
    Class<? super T> rawType = type.getRawType();
    Field field = getJsonInlinedField(rawType);
    if (field == null) {
      return null; // this factory doesn't know how to adapt this type
    }
    field.setAccessible(true);
    TypeAdapter<?> delegate = gson.getAdapter(field.getType());
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") // this creates a type adapter handles for instances of 'T'
    TypeAdapter<T> fieldAdapter = (TypeAdapter<T>) newAdapter(rawType, field, delegate);
    return fieldAdapter;
  }

  private Field getJsonInlinedField(Class<?> c) {
    for (Field field : c.getDeclaredFields()) {
      if (field.isAnnotationPresent(JsonInlined.class)) {
        return field;
      }
    }
    return null;
  }

  static <F> TypeAdapter<Object> newAdapter(final Class<?> c,
      final Field field, final TypeAdapter<F> fieldAdapter) {
    return new TypeAdapter<Object>() {
      @Override public void write(JsonWriter out, Object value) throws IOException {
        try {
          if (value != null) {
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") // we define 'F' by the type of field
            F fieldValue = (F) field.get(value);
            fieldAdapter.write(out, fieldValue);
          } else {
            out.nullValue();
          }
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
          throw new AssertionError(e);
        }
      }
      @Override public Object read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
        try {
          if (in.peek() == JsonToken.NULL) {
            return null;
          } else {
            Object instance = c.newInstance();
            field.set(instance, fieldAdapter.read(in));
            return instance;
          }
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
          throw new AssertionError(e);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
          throw new AssertionError(e);
        }
      }
    };
  }
}
```

I'm not going to explain the entire implementation; there's a decent description of the moving parts in the [TypeAdapter](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/TypeAdapter.html) and [TypeAdapterFactory](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/TypeAdapterFactory.html) javadocs.

The most important thing to remember is that you can *compose* type adapters with other type adapters. The factory API forces you to do all of your reflection up front. This helps to catch errors earlier, and it also helps your code to run more efficiently.

Comment: And don't forget to use GsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapterFactory(new InlinedFieldFactory()) to take advantage of this beast!

Comment: Unfortunately we use gson 1.7.1 and for now we can't migrate to new version.

Comment: Why not? (I'm a Gson maintainer; I'm always curious why people can't get the new hotness.)